# How to validate the controls in the form with the TabPanel controls in Ext.net

Tags: validation, ext.net

> Hi I have to implement the validation functionality like if all the  form controls with in the Tabpanels is valid then it should enable the  "Save" button otherwise it should be disabled. 
>   In this marked as * are  required fields  and corresponding Code Sa

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<html>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ext:ResourceManager ID="reso" SourceFormatting="true" runat="server" />
            <ext:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" AutoHeight="true" Layout="VBoxLayout" Border="false"
                AutoScroll="true">
                <LayoutConfig>
                    <ext:VBoxLayoutConfig Align="Left" />
                </LayoutConfig>
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel ID="pnlEditInfo" Header="false" Border="false" runat="server" Title="Basic Info"
                        Width="950" AutoHeight="true" AutoScroll="true" Layout="Form" ButtonAlign="Center"
                        Padding="5" MinHeight="550">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:FormPanel ID="fpnlCreateStatus" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                Width="850" Border="false">
                                <Items>

                                    <ext:Container runat="server" ID="ContnOne" Layout="ColumnLayout" Width="700" MinHeight="120">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Container runat="server" Layout="Form" ColumnWidth=".5" ID="ContOneChild">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:TextField ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Company Name" Cls="labelStyle"
                                                        AnchorHorizontal="95%" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="Company Name is required"
                                                        MaskRe="/[a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/" MaxLength="240" PaddingSpec="8 0 0 0" Width="350" LabelAlign="Right"
                                                        LabelWidth="135">
                                                    </ext:TextField>
                                                    <ext:TextField ID="txtShortName" MaskRe="/[A-Za-z/_/-/ ]/" Cls="labelStyle" MaxLength="25" LabelWidth="135" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="Short Name is required"
                                                        LabelAlign="Right" Width="350" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Short Name" AnchorHorizontal="95%" />

                                                    <ext:RadioGroup ID="rghasMultipleLoc" LabelWidth="135" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server"
                                                        FieldLabel="Has Multiple Locations?" Width="250">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:Radio ID="rdMultiLocYes" runat="server" BoxLabel="Yes" Checked="true" />
                                                            <ext:Radio ID="rdMultiLocNo" runat="server" BoxLabel="No" />
                                                        </Items>
                                                    </ext:RadioGroup>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Container>
                                        </Items>
                                    </ext:Container>
                                    <ext:TabPanel ID="tbpnlCompany" runat="server" Plain="true" Width="830"
                                        Border="false">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlProfile" runat="server" Title="Profile" Padding="10" Layout="Form"
                                                Border="false" Height="130">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:FormPanel ID="frmCompProfile" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextArea ID="txtCompanyProfile" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Company Profile"
                                                                LabelWidth="150" Height="100" TabIndex="1" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" AllowBlank="false"
                                                                Width="500" BlankText="Company Profile is required" MaskRe="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().-_  ]"
                                                                MaxLength="500" />
                                                        </Items>
                                                        <Listeners>
                                                            <ValidityChange Handler="#{btnSave}.setDisabled(!valid);" />
                                                        </Listeners>
                                                    </ext:FormPanel>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>
                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlAddress" runat="server" Title="Address" Padding="10" Layout="Form"
                                                Border="false" Height="130">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:FormPanel ID="frmPanelAddress" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtAddress1" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Address1"
                                                                TabIndex="2" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" AllowBlank="false" Width="500" BlankText="Address1 is required"
                                                                MaskRe="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().-_  ]" MaxLength="250" />
                                                                  <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" Border="false">
                                                                <Items>
                                                                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" ColumnWidth=".3" Border="false">
                                                                        <Items>
                                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtCity" MaskRe="[A-Za-z ]" MaxLength="50" LabelAlign="Right"
                                                                                runat="server" PaddingSpec="0 0 5 0" TabIndex="4" FieldLabel="City" Width="250"
                                                                                RemoveClearTrigger="true" Cls="labelStyle" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="City Name is required">
                                                                            </ext:TextField>
                                                                            <ext:ComboBox ID="cbCountry" LabelAlign="Right" FieldLabel="* Country" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;"
                                                                                TabIndex="5" runat="server" Editable="false" DisplayField="CountryName" BlankText="Country is required"
                                                                                AllowBlank="false" MsgTarget="Side" ValueField="CountryCode" EmptyText="Select"
                                                                                Resizable="false" SelectOnFocus="true" Width="250">
                                                                                <Items>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="India" Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                         <ext:ListItem Text="U.A.E" Value="3">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </Items>

                                                                            </ext:ComboBox>
                                                                        </Items>
                                                                    </ext:Panel>
                                                                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" ColumnWidth=".3" Border="false">
                                                                        <Items>
                                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtZIP" MaskRe="/[0-9]/" MinLength="6" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server"
                                                                                TabIndex="6" FieldLabel="ZIP Code" Width="250" PaddingSpec="0 0 5 0" />
                                                                            <ext:ComboBox ID="cbState" LabelAlign="Right" MsgTarget="Side" FieldLabel="* State"
                                                                                TabIndex="7" AllowBlank="false" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" runat="server"
                                                                                Editable="false" DisplayField="StateName" ValueField="StateCode" BlankText="State is required"
                                                                                EmptyText="Select" Resizable="false" SelectOnFocus="true" Width="250">
                                                                                <Items>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Andhra Pradesh" Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Kerala" Value="2">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                       <ext:ListItem Text="London" Value="5">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Kentucky" Value="6">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </Items>
                                                                                <SelectedItems>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </SelectedItems>

                                                                            </ext:ComboBox>

                                                                        </Items>
                                                                    </ext:Panel>

                                                                </Items>
                                                            </ext:Panel>
                                                        </Items>
                                                        <Listeners>
                                                            <ValidityChange Handler="#{btnSave}.setDisabled(!valid);" />
                                                        </Listeners>
                                                    </ext:FormPanel>

                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>


                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlCommunication" runat="server" Title="Communication" Border="false" TagString="Communication"
                                                Height="130" Padding="10" Layout="Form">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:FormPanel ID="frmPnlCommunication" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtWebsite" LabelAlign="Right" Regex="/^[A-Za-z0-9-\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/"
                                                                MaxLength="25" InvalidText="Website is invalid" MsgTargetElement="lblErrorMsg" MsgTarget="Side"
                                                                runat="server" TabIndex="8" FieldLabel="Website" Width="500" RegexText="Enter Valid Website">

                                                            </ext:TextField>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtEmailid" LabelAlign="Right" Regex="^(\w+)([-+.][\w]+)*@(\w[-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,4}$"
                                                                MaxLength="50" TabIndex="9" RegexText="Enter correct emailid" runat="server"
                                                                FieldLabel="EmailID" Width="500" />
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtPhone" LabelAlign="Right" BlankText="Phone is required" runat="server"
                                                                TabIndex="10" FieldLabel="Phone" Width="500" MaskRe="/[0-9\-]/" MaxLength="25"
                                                                MaxLengthText="Maximum length for phone is 15" />
                                                                </Items>
                                                        <Listeners>
                                                            <ValidityChange Handler="#{btnSave}.setDisabled(!valid);" />
                                                        </Listeners>
                                                    </ext:FormPanel>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>

                                        </Items>

                                    </ext:TabPanel>
                                    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlButtons" Height="30" Border="false" Width="600"
                                        ButtonAlign="Center">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Cls="buttonstyle" Icon="Disk" Disabled="true"
                                                Text="Save" TabIndex="24" X="250">
                                                <Listeners>

                                                </Listeners>

                                            </ext:Button>
                                            <ext:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Cls="buttonstyle" Text="Cancel" Icon="Cancel"
                                                X="260" TabIndex="25">
                                            </ext:Button>
                                        </Items>
                                    </ext:Panel>
                                </Items>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <ValidityChange Handler="#{btnSave}.setDisabled(!valid);" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:FormPanel>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>

                </Items>
            </ext:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Here it is working fine  for the active tab controls in tabPanel , but  it doesn't validating the  other tabs in the TabPanel control and the save button  enables i.e which is not validating correctly.
>   Suggest me the right way to validate all the controls with in the all  the tabpanels also and enabling the save button after all the controls  were saved.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. Based on this link: http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27203

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ext:ResourceManager ID="reso" SourceFormatting="true" runat="server" />
            <ext:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" AutoHeight="true" Layout="VBoxLayout" Border="false"
                AutoScroll="true">
                <LayoutConfig>
                    <ext:VBoxLayoutConfig Align="Left" />
                </LayoutConfig>
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel ID="pnlEditInfo" Header="false" Border="false" runat="server" Title="Basic Info"
                        Width="950" AutoHeight="true" AutoScroll="true" Layout="Form" ButtonAlign="Center"
                        Padding="5" MinHeight="550">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:FormPanel ID="fpnlCreateStatus" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                Width="850" Border="false">
                                <Items>

                                    <ext:Container runat="server" ID="ContnOne" Layout="ColumnLayout" Width="700" MinHeight="120">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Container runat="server" Layout="Form" ColumnWidth=".5" ID="ContOneChild">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:TextField ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Company Name" Cls="labelStyle"
                                                        AnchorHorizontal="95%" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="Company Name is required"
                                                        MaskRe="/[a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/" MaxLength="240" PaddingSpec="8 0 0 0" Width="350" LabelAlign="Right"
                                                        LabelWidth="135">
                                                    </ext:TextField>
                                                    <ext:TextField ID="txtShortName" MaskRe="/[A-Za-z/_/-/ ]/" Cls="labelStyle" MaxLength="25" LabelWidth="135" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="Short Name is required"
                                                        LabelAlign="Right" Width="350" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Short Name" AnchorHorizontal="95%" />

                                                    <ext:RadioGroup ID="rghasMultipleLoc" LabelWidth="135" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server"
                                                        FieldLabel="Has Multiple Locations?" Width="250">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:Radio ID="rdMultiLocYes" runat="server" BoxLabel="Yes" Checked="true" />
                                                            <ext:Radio ID="rdMultiLocNo" runat="server" BoxLabel="No" />
                                                        </Items>
                                                    </ext:RadioGroup>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Container>
                                        </Items>
                                    </ext:Container>
                                    <ext:TabPanel ID="tbpnlCompany" runat="server" Plain="true" Width="830" DeferredRender="false"
                                        Border="false">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlProfile" runat="server" Title="Profile" Padding="10" Layout="Form"
                                                Border="false" Height="130">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:Panel ID="frmCompProfile" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextArea ID="txtCompanyProfile" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Company Profile"
                                                                LabelWidth="150" Height="100" TabIndex="1" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" AllowBlank="false"
                                                                Width="500" BlankText="Company Profile is required" MaskRe="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().-_  ]"
                                                                MaxLength="500" />
                                                        </Items>
                                                    </ext:Panel>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>
                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlAddress" runat="server" Title="Address" Padding="10" Layout="Form"
                                                Border="false" Height="130">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:Panel ID="frmPanelAddress" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtAddress1" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server" FieldLabel="* Address1"
                                                                TabIndex="2" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" AllowBlank="false" Width="500" BlankText="Address1 is required"
                                                                MaskRe="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().-_  ]" MaxLength="250" />
                                                                  <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" Border="false">
                                                                <Items>
                                                                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" ColumnWidth=".3" Border="false">
                                                                        <Items>
                                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtCity" MaskRe="[A-Za-z ]" MaxLength="50" LabelAlign="Right"
                                                                                runat="server" PaddingSpec="0 0 5 0" TabIndex="4" FieldLabel="City" Width="250"
                                                                                RemoveClearTrigger="true" Cls="labelStyle" AllowBlank="false" BlankText="City Name is required">
                                                                            </ext:TextField>
                                                                            <ext:ComboBox ID="cbCountry" LabelAlign="Right" FieldLabel="* Country" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;"
                                                                                TabIndex="5" runat="server" Editable="false" DisplayField="CountryName" BlankText="Country is required"
                                                                                AllowBlank="false" MsgTarget="Side" ValueField="CountryCode" EmptyText="Select"
                                                                                Resizable="false" SelectOnFocus="true" Width="250">
                                                                                <Items>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="India" Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                         <ext:ListItem Text="U.A.E" Value="3">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </Items>

                                                                            </ext:ComboBox>
                                                                        </Items>
                                                                    </ext:Panel>
                                                                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" ColumnWidth=".3" Border="false">
                                                                        <Items>
                                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtZIP" MaskRe="/[0-9]/" MinLength="6" LabelAlign="Right" runat="server"
                                                                                TabIndex="6" FieldLabel="ZIP Code" Width="250" PaddingSpec="0 0 5 0" />
                                                                            <ext:ComboBox ID="cbState" LabelAlign="Right" MsgTarget="Side" FieldLabel="* State"
                                                                                TabIndex="7" AllowBlank="false" LabelStyle="font-weight: bold;" runat="server"
                                                                                Editable="false" DisplayField="StateName" ValueField="StateCode" BlankText="State is required"
                                                                                EmptyText="Select" Resizable="false" SelectOnFocus="true" Width="250">
                                                                                <Items>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Andhra Pradesh" Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Kerala" Value="2">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                       <ext:ListItem Text="London" Value="5">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Text="Kentucky" Value="6">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </Items>
                                                                                <SelectedItems>
                                                                                    <ext:ListItem Value="1">
                                                                                    </ext:ListItem>
                                                                                </SelectedItems>

                                                                            </ext:ComboBox>

                                                                        </Items>
                                                                    </ext:Panel>

                                                                </Items>
                                                            </ext:Panel>
                                                        </Items>
                                                    </ext:Panel>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>


                                            <ext:Panel ID="pnlCommunication" runat="server" Title="Communication" Border="false" TagString="Communication"
                                                Height="130" Padding="10" Layout="Form">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <ext:Panel ID="frmPnlCommunication" Cls="formBackground" runat="server" BodyCls="formheader"
                                                        Padding="5" ButtonAlign="Center" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="false" MonitorValid="true"
                                                        Width="850" Border="false">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtWebsite" LabelAlign="Right" Regex="/^[A-Za-z0-9-\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/"
                                                                MaxLength="25" InvalidText="Website is invalid" MsgTargetElement="lblErrorMsg" MsgTarget="Side"
                                                                runat="server" TabIndex="8" FieldLabel="Website" Width="500" RegexText="Enter Valid Website">

                                                            </ext:TextField>
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtEmailid" LabelAlign="Right" Regex="^(\w+)([-+.][\w]+)*@(\w[-\w]*\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,4}$"
                                                                MaxLength="50" TabIndex="9" RegexText="Enter correct emailid" runat="server"
                                                                FieldLabel="EmailID" Width="500" />
                                                            <ext:TextField ID="txtPhone" LabelAlign="Right" BlankText="Phone is required" runat="server"
                                                                TabIndex="10" FieldLabel="Phone" Width="500" MaskRe="/[0-9\-]/" MaxLength="25"
                                                                MaxLengthText="Maximum length for phone is 15" />
                                                                </Items>
                                                    </ext:Panel>
                                                </Items>
                                            </ext:Panel>

                                        </Items>

                                    </ext:TabPanel>
                                    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlButtons" Height="30" Border="false" Width="600"
                                        ButtonAlign="Center">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Cls="buttonstyle" Icon="Disk" Disabled="true"
                                                Text="Save" TabIndex="24" X="250">
                                                <Listeners>

                                                </Listeners>

                                            </ext:Button>
                                            <ext:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Cls="buttonstyle" Text="Cancel" Icon="Cancel"
                                                X="260" TabIndex="25">
                                            </ext:Button>
                                        </Items>
                                    </ext:Panel>
                                </Items>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <ValidityChange Handler="#{btnSave}.setDisabled(!valid);" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:FormPanel>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>

                </Items>
            </ext:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```